# LibGDX AssetManager, как заставить копировать объект?

Tags: java, libgdx

Каким образом и возможно ли заставить `AssetManager` копировать объект при вызове `load()`?

Comment: Куда копировать ?

Comment: Клонировать. Создать точно такой же.

Comment: Где создать то?